# Why is Spring's BeanWrapper#getPropertyValue so slow?

Tags: java, spring, reflection

This is my test method.

I'm trying to invoke this method 100000 times.

#### With Spring's BeanWrapper

Following using `BeanWrapper.getPropertyValue` costs 12000 ms.

```java
private static void test() {
    MyBean bean = new MyBean();
    Field[] fields = MyBean.class.getDeclaredFields();
    BeanWrapper beanWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(bean);
    for (Field f : fields) {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        String fieldName = f.getName();
        Object fieldValue = beanWrapper.getPropertyValue(fieldName);
    }
}
```

#### Using Java introspection

And when I change the code to use [`Field.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object)) it only costs about 400 ms.

```java
private static void test() {
    MyBean bean = new MyBean();
    Field[] fields = MyBean.class.getDeclaredFields();
    BeanWrapper beanWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(bean);
    for (Field f : fields) {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        String fieldName = f.getName();
        Object fieldValue = f.get(bean);
        // Object fieldValue = beanWrapper.getPropertyValue(fieldName);
    }
}
```

Why is Spring's [BeanWrapper.getPropertyValue](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.html#getPropertyValue-java.lang.String-) so slow?

Comment: Because it does things in a more ["frameworkey" way](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/0783f0762d72df70572aaceeee099c3ec4b7e019/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java#L613).

Comment: Bean properties are defined by the public getter methods. So the expected behavior would be to invoke the getter method rather than doing `setAccessible(true)` and `get(…)` on the field. But searching for the named getter method requires linear iteration over [the descriptors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/BeanInfo.html#getPropertyDescriptors()). Unless there’s caching, but populating a `HashMap` isn’t cheap either. But even if it did use a `Field`: you’re requesting the value *by name* and comparing with your code already having the `Field`.

Comment: @Holger thank you for reply. Is there a cheaper way to invoke public getter methods with caching?

Comment: This heavily depends on the actual use case. Any structure built for speeding up lookups is only useful if it will be used often enough to compensate the time needed to build it.